# Unable to modify Recovery Actions for a service

Tags: service, windows-server-2019

I have a service (NameOfService.exe) that frequently shuts down on its own. I haven't yet figured out why it keeps stopping. I want to trigger an alert for when it does shutdown. I assume that this can be done via the Recovery Options. I also want to use the Recovery Options to attempt and automatic restart of the service. However, these options are grayed out and I am unable to configure them. I am logged in with an Administrator account. I even used the Run As Administrator option to load the services screen. These Recovery Options are still grayed out.

Can anyone tell me why they might be grayed out and how to fix that? Also, does anyone have an idea on how to trigger an email alert for when a service stops running?